# SQL Server transaction and SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server

I often saw many people use `SELECT` statement within a transaction. I often use `insert/update/delete` only in transaction. I just do not understand that what is the utility of putting a `SELECT` statement inside transaction.

I got one answer that....`SELECT` inside the transaction can see changes made by other previous `Insert/Update/Delete` statements in that transaction, a `SELECT` statement outside the transaction cannot.

Above statement is it true or not ?

Is this is the only reason that people put `SELECT` statement inside transaction? Please discuss all the reason in detail if possible. thanks

Comment: If you're using the default isolation level (`READ COMMITTED`) - then yes - a `SELECT` outside the transaction will **not** see any insert or updates a transaction has made, until those are actually committed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try doing this and you will understand:

Open a two new queries on SSMS (lets call it A and B from now one) and on A, create a simple table like this:

```
create table transTest(id int)
insert into transTest values(1)
```

now, do the following:

do `select * from transTest` in both of them. You will see the value 1

On A run:

```
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

On B run:

```
begin transaction
insert into transTest values(2)
```

On A run:

`select * from transTest`

you will see that the query wont finish because it is locked by the transaction on A

On B run:

```
commit transaction
```

Go back to A and you will see that the query finished

Repeat the test with 
`set transaction isolation level read uncommitted` on A
you will see that the query wont be locked by the transaction

Comment: thanks for answer. can u plzz tell me what is "isolation level read committed" ? what does it mean "isolation level read committed" as per your explanation it will be table lock but i want to lock only row. so guide me. thanks

Comment: every transaction has an isolation level. Read committed is the default and it means that you will only read data already saved to the disk. 
You may want to google a little about isolation levels, there is a lot of material out there and would be hard to summarize here

Answer (score 5):

One of the main reasons I can think of (the only reason, in fact) is if you want to set a different [isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx), eg:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT * FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory;

SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Department;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

For single SELECT statements though, I'm not so sure, unless you had a reason to go the other way and set READ UNCOMMITTED in cases where response time/maximising concurrency is more important than accurate or valid data.

**<speculation certainty="75%">** If the single SELECT statement is inside an explicit transaction without altering the isolation levels, I'm pretty sure that will have no effect at all. Individual statements are, by themselves, transactions that are auto-committed or rolled back on error.**</speculation>**